# The degree of simple radical extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, radicals

Let $m \le n$ be positive integers. Does there necessarily exist a field extension $K/F$ such that $[K:F] = m$ and $K = F(u)$ for some $u \in K$ satisfying $u^{n} \in F$?

In other words, given $m \le n$, does there exist a field $F$ and an element $a \in F$ such that the polynomial $x^{n}-a \in F[x]$ has an irreducible factor of degree $m$?

Comment: @reuns I only want to fix $m,n$ so $F,K$ are allowed to be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Let $E$ be the splitting field of $x^n-1\in F[x]$.
- Let $p=char(f)$, if $p\ne 0$ then let $n=p^r s$ with $p\nmid s$, otherwise let $s=n$. Then $E=F(\zeta_s)$, $E/F$ is Galois, and $Gal(E/F)$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}/s\Bbb{Z}^\times$. Whence $[E:F]$ divides $\phi(s)$ which divides $\phi(n)$.
- Given $u^n\in E$, let $f\in E[x]$ be the minimal polynomial of $u$, we have $f(0)= u^{\deg(f)} \zeta_s^l$ so that $u^{\deg(f)}\in E$ which implies that $u^{\gcd(n,\deg f)}\in E$. Therefore $[E(u):E]=\deg f$ divides $n$.
- $[F(u):F]$ divides $[E(u):F]$ which divides $n \phi(n)$.
- If $m$ doesn't divide $n \phi(n)$ then it can't be that $[F(u):F]=m$.